# How can I use <h:outputScript /> with a remote file?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a server dedicated for static contents so I don't want to use the resources dir for storing javascript files but I don't want to stop using the `<h:outputScript />` tag.

How can I make that tag generate a link to my static server where the files are located instead of **RES_NOT_FOUND**. I don't even need JSF to check if the files are there...

I tried: `<h:outputScript name="#{requestBean.staticURL}/javascript.js"/>`

To generate: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.server.com/javascript.js"></script>`

But it generates: `<script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>`

What can I do?

**SOLUTION:**
Daniel pointed me to a nice solution!

I've downloaded the Omnifaces's source code and modified the `org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandle.createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName)` method to:

```
public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
    final Resource resource = wrapped.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);

    if (cdnResources == null) {
        return resource;
    }

    String resourceId = ((libraryName != null) ? libraryName + ":" : "") + resourceName;

    String path = cdnResources.get(resourceId);

    if(path == null){
        if(libraryName != null){
            resourceId = libraryName + ":%";
            path = cdnResources.get(resourceId);
            if(path == null){
                return resource;
            }
            path += "/"+resourceName;
        }
        else return resource;
    }

    final String requestPath = path;

    return new ResourceWrapper() {

        @Override
        public String getRequestPath() {
            return requestPath;
        }

        @Override
        public Resource getWrapped() {
            return resource;
        }
    };
}
```

With this change I can add this to my **web.xml** file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        somelib2:%=http://cdn.example.com/somelib2,
        js/script1.js=http://cdn.example.com/js/script1.js,
        somelib:js/script2.js=http://cdn.example.com/somelib/js/script2.js,
        otherlib:style.css=http://cdn.example.com/otherlib/style.css,
        images/logo.png=http://cdn.example.com/logo.png
   </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Notice the `somelib2:%=http://cdn.example.com/somelib2`, this will point any resource in **somelib2** library to the relative path in **http://cdn.example.com/somelib2**, for example:

`<h:outputScript name="js/myjs.js" library="somelib2" />`

will output:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.example.com/somelib2/js/myjs.js"></script>`

This works with `<h:outputScript /><h:outputStylesheet /><h:graphicImage />`, anything that use resources;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't

Simply because `<h:outputScript />` can read **only** form local resource folder inside your web app

**What you could do is use** [Omnifaces CDNResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler) , and here is the [JavaDoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/CDNResourceHandler.html)

It will allow you to use  with a remote file

*Here some code from the showcase*

To get it to run, this handler needs be registered as follows in faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>



<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        js/script1.js=http://cdn.example.com/js/script1.js,
        somelib:js/script2.js=http://cdn.example.com/somelib/js/script2.js,
        otherlib:style.css=http://cdn.example.com/otherlib/style.css,
        images/logo.png=http://cdn.example.com/logo.png
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

With the above configuration, the following resources:

```
<h:outputScript name="js/script1.js" />
<h:outputScript library="somelib" name="js/script2.js" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="otherlib" name="style.css" />
<h:graphicImage name="images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion helped me a lot and solved my problem :)
I changed the CDNResourceHandle.createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) method to allow the use of library to link to my server instead of listing every single file and now it's working perfectly :)

Comment: If you are interested in the change, I've changed this part:
`String resourceId = ((libraryName != null) ? libraryName + ":" : "") + resourceName;

String path = cdnResources.get(resourceId);

if(path == null){
 if(libraryName != null){
  resourceId = libraryName + ":%";
  path = cdnResources.get(resourceId);
  if(path == null){
   return resource;
  }
  path += "/"+resourceName;
 }
 else return resource;
}

final String requestPath = path;`

Comment: This will do the job: `<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        alibraryname:%=http://cdn.example.com
    </param-value>
</context-param>`, now you can do this: `<h:outputScript name="js/javascript.js" library="alibraryname" />`

Comment: And the result will be: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.example.com/js/javascript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need that. It is used to display a script taken from archives in your classpath. For a regular script you can simply type the corresponding `<script>` tag.