# Pointing to resources located on a remote CDN

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I would like my server to point to resource files (i.e. css, js, images that are under /resources/default/VERSION_NUMBER/) to AWS S3 instead of delivering the files to the client side by itself.

Here are the relevant libraries and their version number taken from the pom file:

```
<javax.servlet-api.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
<weld-servlet.version>2.2.9.Final</weld-servlet.version>
<javax.el-api.version>3.0.0</javax.el-api.version>
<el-impl.version>2.2</el-impl.version>
<tomcat-jdbc.version>7.0.47</tomcat-jdbc.version>
<javax.faces.version>2.2.10</javax.faces.version>
<omnifaces.version>2.3</omnifaces.version>
<primefaces.version>6.1</primefaces.version>
```

I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667052/how-can-i-use-houtputscript-with-a-remote-file) and modified my web.xml file with the following lines:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        remote:*=https://[URL]
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And updated the library tag in all my css, javascript and image files mentioned in my xhtml file accordingly.

example:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="styles/header.css"/>
```

Is modified to

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="remote" name="styles/header.css"/>
```

Now I am noticing that while the css files are loaded properly from the remote server, the url tags such the following present in the css files (hosted on the remote server) are not being downloaded from the local or remote server

```
background-image: url("#{resource['remote:images/add-default.png']}") !important;
```

Note that everything under my resource folder is already hosted in my remote server. I imagine JSF is failing to properly create the url from #{resource['remote:images/add-default.png'}] because in firefox console I get the error "The resource at “” was blocked because content blocking is enabled." for these files.

Once I figure out how to fix this, I would also like to know how to make it so all the jsf resources required on the client side that I don't explicitly specify in my xhtml files can be also hosted in the remote server.

Thank you!

Comment: Some small comments: Only tag questions [tag:java] if it is pure jdk related and nothing more is needed. 2: You use plain jsf and omnifaces in the question yet you **tag** it with richfaces and not omnifaces. 3: please post version info of the relevant libraries (and for JSF also the implementation, Mojarra or MyFaces)

Comment: I have added the relevant libraries and their version numbers to the post.